# mod rewrite based on just one parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Evening, I'm trying to do a rule to convert this:

```
https://example.com/pt/herbario/cons_reg_ncom2.asp?ncomum=Marmeleiro+unedo&Submit3=Pesquisar&ID=1640
```

into this:

```
https://example.com/pesquisa/ncomum/Marmeleiro+unedo
```

Right now I have this:

```
RewriteRule ^pt/herbario/cons_reg_ncom2.asp(.*)$ /pesquisa/ncomum/$1 [L, QSA]
```

But according to http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ this redirects to a URL like this:

```
https://example.com/pesquisa/ncomum/?ncomum=Marmeleiro+unedo&Submit3=Pesquisar&ID=1640
```

I already tried to change to `([^&])` but with no luck ... what am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query string is not part of the RewriteRule URI. You must use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)ncomum=([^&]*)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^pt/herbario/cons_reg_ncom2\.asp$ /pesquisa/ncomum/%1? [NC,L]
```

Comment: If you try to redirect, change `[NC,L]` to `[NC,R=301]`